# Is there a way I can get rid of the error. I perfomed an Auto-Arima model before this and modelled ARIMA(3,1,2)

Tags: python, forecasting, arima

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py:393: ValueWarning: No supported index is available. Prediction results will be given with an integer index beginning at `start`.
  ValueWarning)

# Forecast

fc, se, conf = fitted.forecast(519, alpha=0.05)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-79-4e0fb5022962> in <module>()
      1 # Forecast
      2 
----> 3 fc, se, conf = fitted.forecast(519, alpha=0.05)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You try to save what a function is returning, in this case you expect three values. One for fc, one for se and one for conf. The problem is that the function .forecast() returns the prediction as a single object. You try to unpack a single object, but Python expects three. Therefore, “too many values to unpack…”. You can read the documentation of the function here to check what it returns:

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.forecast

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.html

If you try this it will save all predictions in the object “preds” as a pandas Series:

`preds = fitted.forecast(519, alpha=0.05)`